# connect to redis server on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, remote-access

I am trying to connect to redis server running on EC2. I uncomment the bind line in redis conf file.

```
>> netstat -nlpt | grep 6379
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

but I still could not connect to it with the following command:

```
redis-cli -h ec2-xx-xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

Am i missing something here? I am able to connect the the ec2 box through ssh:

```
ssh -i ~/.ec2/ec2.pem ubuntu@ec2-xx-xx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have port 6379 accessible in your security policy?

Comment: @Mike Brant Where to set it? In AWS?

Comment: If you are working in AWS Console, then you need go go modify the security policy associated with the instance to accept incoming traffic on port 6379.

Comment: @MikeBrant Thanks, it works after I set a new rule for the inbound.

Comment: Good.  I have added answer below for any future visitors to this question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to set the security policy associated with the instance to allow for inbound traffic on port 6379.